# Asp Net 1.1 - OnClientClick event in LinkButton not firing before OnClick Event

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, events

So i have this form defined with a couple of fields to fill and a submit button which is supposed to trigger an OnClick event defined in the code behind to collect the filled data and send it to the local database. However, this event should be triggered only after certain fields have been validated using an OnClientClick event which invokes a Javascript function to make the necessary field validations (such as searching for duplicate values and if certain fields are filled) before sending the information. In this case, the OnClick event should be triggered only after the OnClientClick event fires and returns "true" which is not happening. The submit button fires even  How can i get around this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your code please!

Comment: Never rely only on javascript code for validation. It's trivial to fake a click with anything you want in the request.

Comment: Actually, it works fine now. I forgot to add a statement at the end of one of the validation functions in order to return a boolean value. Either way, i appreciate you guys for taking the time!